# C# GPGPU Library Hybrid Error

Tags: c#, gpgpu

I'm new to GPGPU computing. I found this online library called [Hybrid](http://hybrid.codeplex.com/). they say

"Hybrid.Net enables .NET developers to harness the power of GPUs for data- and compute-intense applications using the simple well-known construct: Parallel.For"

I downloaded the library and when i run the helloworld application they provide which is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Hybrid.Gpu;
using Hybrid.MsilToOpenCL;
using Hybrid;
using OpenCLNet;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                        //define vectors a, b and c
            int vectorLength = 1024;
            int[] a = new int[vectorLength];
            int[] b = new int[vectorLength];
            int[] c = new int[vectorLength];

            //initialize vectors a, b and c

            //execute vector addition on GPU
            Hybrid.Parallel.For(Execute.OnSingleGpu, 0, vectorLength, delegate(int i)
            {
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

i get

```
   An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Hybrid.MsilToOpenCL.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for 'OpenCLNet.OpenCL' threw an exception.
```

can anyone tell me what's happening here?

(just so you know im new to StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the inner exception. It will have the details you need.

Comment: You mean like try catch thing?. I tried nothing works i get the message i showed you above.

Comment: @KamalRathnayake when you say "I get", you're putting down the exception message. But that exception object has an "InnerException" property. That property sometimes is null, but when a type initialization exception occurs, it stores the original exception in the InnerException property. It should give you more information as to what failed in that type initialization.